# pytest - How to make it search recursively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have the following `tests` directory tree:

```
tests/
  subfolder_1/
    test_1.py
  subfolder_2/
    subsubfolder/
      subsubsubfolder/
        test_2.py
```

py.test only finds `test_1.py`. How can I make it find `test_2.py`?

Answer (score 17):

pytest always searches recursively unless you tell it otherwise (with the [`norecursedirs`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#confval-norecursedirs) option).

If pytest is failing to collect some of your tests, double check that:

1. the test files are somewhere under the [`testpaths`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths) configuration pattern (default: the current directory),
2. the test files match the [`python_files`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files) configuration pattern (default: `test_*.py` and `*_test.py`),
3. the test classes match the [`python_classes`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#confval-python_classes) configuration pattern (default: `Test*`), and
4. the test functions match the [`python_functions`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#confval-python_functions) configuration pattern (default: `test*`).

Comment: ad. 2) It is strange for me that `pytest -s -v test/*` found all modules named `test_*.py` but ignored modules named `*_test.py`. When I changed suffix **test** to prefix, it works correctly.
Anyway thanks for advice, it helped me with this issue :)

Answer (score 5):

`Pytest` has some issues finding files named `test.py` or similar. Try giving it a more specialised name such as `test_subfolder1.py` and `test_subfolder2.py` or so. Also make sure that all you folders are packages i.e. have `__init__.py` file in them.

Comment: Ahh, my bad, I forgot to name the test class `TestClass` .. No need to rename the folders or add `__init__.py` :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint on pytest having trouble with files named `test.py`